# ASP.NET display a message between two dates?

Tags: asp.net, date

I have a message that needs to be displayed on an order form over the holidays regarding possible delayed shipping. I know how to do this in PHP, with a simple if/else using the `date()` function. Is there something similar in ASP.net?

Comment: Is this ASP.net (as noted in the subject) or ASP as noted in the tags and your sentence?

Comment: ASP.net. I'll modify the question.

Comment: to make sure I understand the question right. You want to display a message if the current date is equal to or greater then something?

Comment: Correct. I want to display a message if today's date is greater than or equal to date-x and less than or equal to date-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming inline script instead of code behind and C# and not Razor view eng.

```
<% if (DateTime.Now >= date-x && DateTime.Now <= date-y) { %>
enter message here
<%}%>
```

Comment: Inline script is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I should have specified that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net has a DateTime class that will work.

```
var holidayList = new List<DateTime> {[YourHolidayList]}
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;

if (holidayList.Contains(today))
{[DelayedShippingMessage]}
```